# Django Rest Framework: Transforming Model For Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an invite model that maps Inviters to Invitees `user` and `to_user`. However I need to return just the list of users to the client. How should I transform a queryset of Invite Objects (just `id`, `user`, and `to_user`) into a query of users mapping to that `to_user field`? Here's what I have so far.

```
class Invite(AbstractBaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='invites',
                             verbose_name=_('User'))

    to_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                   unique=True,  # Each user can only redeem one code.
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='invitees',
                                   error_messages={'unique': _('You\'ve already claimed an invite.')},
                                   verbose_name=_('To User'))

class InvitesViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def list(self, request):
        """
        List all people invited by the request.user
        """
        invite_objects = Invite.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        invited_users = ??? (Users.objects.filter(id__in=invite_objects.to_user.id?) <- ?
        serializer = UserSerializer(invited_users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
invite_user_ids = Invite.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('to_user', flat=True)
invited_users = Users.objects.filter(id__in=invite_user_ids)
```

Not going to mark as answered yet, does anyone have any issues with this solution?